# Popup Facebook feed iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to implement the Facebook sdk into my app but am having issue displaying the write to wall/feed popup. I Can log in successfully into Facebook from my app. First it takes me to the native Facebook app, once I authorize it, it takes me back to my default app and nothing happens. The dialog box does not appear and all I see is my empty view I created. This is my code, if anyone knows why this is not working I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

**fbViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface fbViewController : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate,FBSessionDelegate,FBDialogDelegate>
{
 Facebook *facebook;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
@end
```

**fbViewController.m**

```
#import "fbViewController.h"
#define kAppId @"xxxxxxx"

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"xxxxxxxxxxx" andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}

}

 - (void)fbDidLogin {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];


NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               kAppId, @"app_id",
                               @"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                               @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                               @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                               @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                               @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
                               nil];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

  }
```

**myAppDelegate.m**

```
// Pre iOS 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
   return [facebook handleOpenUrl:url];
  }

// For iOS 4.2+ support
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
 }
```

Comment: Did you try setrting a breakpoint to make sure that your [facebook dialog:andParams:andDelegate:] is called?

Comment: I would first use NSLog statements in fbDidLogIn and (assuming you send a request of some kind somewhere in your code) in request:didLoad: to see whether login is successful and whether you are actually receiving data. If you are in fact logged in and getting data, then your issue is with how you are putting that data on the view. But from what we have here, there's no way of knowing that.

Comment: @Inturbidus The app never enters fbDidLogin. I have no idea why. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @geraldWilliam The app never enters fbDidLogin. I have no idea why. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036624/facebook-sso-in-ios5) my SO question that I posted while trying to get it sorted out. It might be worth it to implement the test that dmirkitanov suggests in his answer. It's out of the Hackbook app (the one that you get with the facebook-ios-sdk).

Long story short, what I had to do was delete my app from the Facebook developer site, delete it from the iTunes store, submit it all over again from square one on both, and use the new app ID info etc in my code. I think  there was some issue with how it was registered on Facebook's end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply gerald but this seems rather extreme and I would not like to go this route, I feel there is a simply thing I am missing

Comment: I felt the same, for sure. I just wanted to let you know that if, as I did, you end up banging your head against the wall for a week trying to resolve it, that that's what fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

It seems, AppId is incorrect. Try to use another app Id and check

1) Info -> FacebookAppID is same this app id in your code